# Integral with respect to Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, statistics, definite-integrals

I want to integrate the following, but am not sure exactly how to do so. I'm working with a probability distribution $F(x)$ (i.e. $f(x)$ is a density function):

$$\int_0^\infty \int_t ^\infty x^k dF(x) dt$$

I know I can write this as:
$$\int_0^\infty \int_t ^\infty x^k f(x) dx dt$$
But I fail to see how this helps with simplification. I'm tempted to somehow call the inner $E[x^k]$, but that seems incorrect, as we're integrating from $t$ to $\infty$. Would really appreciate some help with this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interchanging the order of integration you get $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{x} dt x^{k}f(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty} x^{k+1} f(x)dx$. If your random variable $X$ is positive this is just $EX^{k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm more than a little rusty on integrals so I hope you'll forgive me if this question is silly, but how were you able to change the bounds from $t$ to $\infty$ to 0 to $\infty$?

Comment: Oh I think I understand-- you've also shifted the bounds on the new inner integral to ensure that $0 \leq t \leq x$, effectively keeping the same bounds.

Comment: I'm just interested by your question: how/why do you shift the bounds on the new inner integral?

Comment: First tackling the why: I think the reason we shift the bounds of the integral is because the way it is when we're integrating in the order of $dx dt$ seems to lead to little progress (as it is tricky to integrate the inner integral with respect to $x$). Luckily, we can see that the inner integrand has no factor of $t$, which means that switching the order of integration can make our life a lot easier.

Comment: As for the how, while I'm not familiar with all the rules of bounds shifting with double integrals; the fact that we have no factor of $t$ in our inner integrand I belive makes our life a lot easier. Intuitively, we can see that we are still integrating over the same range. In the original version, we see that $t \in [0, \infty)$, $x \in [t, \infty]$. Now we have $x \in [0, \infty]$, $t \in [0, x]$ which seems to be an equivalent range.

Comment: @invictus135 You have made the right observations I think you now understand the whole thing.